# Unable to mount CIFS share, but able to mount on others

Tags: redhat, cifs

I have a working windows 2008 R2 file share that I can connect to from one server (running redhat 6.6) with the following syntax in /etc/fstab

`//servername/ELK\es1 /ES1  cifs username=domain\user,password=password 0 0`

From here I run sudo mount -a and it mounts successfully, and I can view files in the share if I run ls /ES1

I have another server (the one I actually want the share mounted on), which runs redhat 7.2, and using the exact same syntax in /etc/fstab, and running a sudo mount -av I get the following error: 
`mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

If I run dmesg I get the following information

`CIFS VFS: RFC 1002 unknown response type 0xa
CIFS VFS: RFC 1002 unknown response type 0xa
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112`

I've updated my iptables, and even flushed them so I do not believe it's an issue with ports being blocked.  The version of cifs-utils is the same, 1.74.

The only thing I can think that's a difference between the two servers is the version of the OS, one being 6.6 and the other being 7.2.

Comment: A simple question, can you actually reach/ping the Windows server by it's name from redhat 7.2 server?

Comment: yes, it's pingable. I have also tried using the IP instead of FQDN and same behavior.

Comment: Can you also make sure, that no firewall or antivirus at the windows server are not blocking connection attempt from the redhat 7.2 server?

Comment: smb 1 is turned off on the windows server. Redhat 6 smbclient only supports smb1, Redhat 7 supports smb2

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I have issues I check the following.  I have found I typically forget step *b*, then try to forge ahead until I get blocked on step *e*.

1. Do you have the `cifs-utils` package installed?  It seems so since it at least printed the `cifs.mount` output.  Typically I find cifs and samba as different packages.
2. Does the connection work if connecting via `smbclient`? See [Mount.cifs vs. SMBClient](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327413/mount-cifs-vs-smbclient) for an example.  This will isolate the mount application.  You will need the samba packages for this.
3. Try to connect with cifs.mount directly with verbose output per [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs).
4. Check the Window-Server event logs to see if the request for a connection is making it to the server.
5. Beef up the log levels on cifs per the debug section [here](http://initrd.org/wiki/CIFS_Client_Setup)
6. Check connectivity in both directions between servers.  Make sure the ports for CIFS are open on each end.  You can check with nmap.
7. Check the network configuration of the two Linux servers to make sure there is not some IT device that is stopping one server but not the other.

Finally, I googled some of the error output and got a few links to some options.  The Ubuntu pages offer a lot of usage info that is generic.

- CIFS VFS User Guide (Authored by non other than [Steve French](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ox3lqBkFuJ4) ). https://pserver.samba.org/samba/ftp/cifs-cvs/linux-cifs-client-guide.pdf
- [Similar problem](https://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2005-April/000792.html).  All findings of error code -112 always point to the Window's end of the pipe.
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

Answer (score 0):

If the normal network reachability using hostname or IP address is working. Then please check and make sure that any Firewall or Antivirus at the Windows Server are not blocking connection attempt from the RedHat 7.2 server.

The error signifies clearly that there is such an issue and that the Redhat Server is unable to connect to the Windows on required ports.

Comment: I flushed the IP tables and tried it and that didn't work.  Also I can connect to the share from other redhat servers so Windows isn't mucking things up.

Comment: Well, I'm not talking about the Redhat Firewall, rather the Windows Firewall. Have you checked that one? If one host is able to connect to it, doesn't mean all other hosts will be able too. May be you have some host/ip specific rules setup at the Windows server. Do you have access to the Windows server?

Comment: windows firewall is off.

Comment: No Antivirus too? Then run Wireshark at the windows server and try to mount the share, then you will see what is happening, if the requests are reaching it or not.

Comment: AV is running, but doesn't appear to be blocking anything.

Comment: Disable it for a moment and try. It won't harm anything.